# Django low performance with Mysql on seperate Instance

Tags: mysql, django, google-cloud-sql

I have configured my application on Goolge Cloud Platform. 
I am using CloudSQL for database connection. Here my database params in settings.

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '133.193.218.243'
            'NAME': 'test',
            'USER': 'test',
            'PASSWORD': 'test',
    }
}
```

http://staging.audiotube.com/test/ this url doesn't have any database interaction it just show the static html. But It takes 3 to 4 seconds for First Byte. Obviously the above mentioned database is on seperate instance.

I have changed the Database to

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
    }
}
```

So this will be installed in local this time http://staging.audiotube.com/test/ would take only 400milliseconds to load.

Questions?

1. Why this much of delay for the First Byte and How to reduce this?
2. On every request DB connection will open? even if there is static pages?

Comment: Hey try https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html  and see which query is taking time while using google cloud sql.

Comment: @Jickson http://staging.audiotube.com/test/  this page doesn't have any query but it was creating the connection I think